# Django and absolute url with slug

Tags: django, model, slug

my model is like:

```
class Modeloxy(models.Model):
      ...
      ...
      slug = models.slug()


class mymodel(models.Model):
      marca = ...
      ...
      modelo = models.ForeignKey(Modeloxy)


      def get_absolute_url(self):
          return '/%s/%s/%s' % (self.marca,self.modelo__slug,self.pk)
```

So, i can't get the absolute url usin self.modelo__slug.... how i will do that?

thanks guys

Comment: On the side note: consider using the reverse function to decouple urls from models http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#django.conf.urls.defaults.reverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be `self.modelo.slug`

The double underscore syntax was created to solve the problem of not being able to use dot syntax as a keyword argument `function(keyword_arg=Foo)` and unrelated to python: you're literally looking for a variable named `modelo__slug` in your case.